# Tkinter Multithreading Freezing Issue

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am currently facing a problem, in which the output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHupI.jpg is needed to be printed into the GUI https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkiCu.jpg. However the problem that I currently faced is that my Tkinter GUI freeze when I run the code, so I am not sure that actually will the details printed on the textbox or not. Is there anyway to make the GUI not hang when using, so I can check whether the details are printed on the textbox. Multithreadding is used but no avail.

```
b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Deep Learning", command=lambda:[threading.Thread(target=learningPart(self,"./data/",100)).start()],borderwidth=0, width=50, height=3, fg="pink", bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 16,'bold'))
        b1.pack()
```

Full Code

```
class deepLearning(tk.Frame):
    
    def display(self, record):
            msg = self.queue_handler.format(record)
            self.scrolled_text.configure(state='normal')
            self.scrolled_text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n', record.levelname)
            self.scrolled_text.configure(state='disabled')
            self.display(record)
            # Autoscroll to the bottom
            self.scrolled_text.yview(tk.END)
            
            
    def poll_log_queue(self):
        # Check every 100ms if there is a new message in the queue to display
            while True:
                try:
                    record = self.log_queue.get(block=False)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break
                else:
                    self.display(record)
            self.after(100, self.poll_log_queue)
            
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            
        def imshow(inp, title):
            data_dir="./data/"
            num_epochs=100
            """Imshow for Tensor."""
            inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
            mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
            std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
            inp = std * inp + mean
            inp = np.clip(inp, 0, 1)
            plt.imshow(inp)
            plt.title(title)
            plt.show()

        def plot(val_loss,train_loss,typ):
            data_dir="./data/"
            num_epochs=100
            plt.title("{} after epoch: {}".format(typ,len(train_loss)))
            plt.xlabel("Epoch")
            plt.ylabel(typ)
            plt.plot(list(range(len(train_loss))),train_loss,color="r",label="Train "+typ)
            plt.plot(list(range(len(val_loss))),val_loss,color="b",label="Validation "+typ)
            plt.legend()
            plt.savefig(os.path.join(data_dir,typ+".png"))
        #     plt.figure()
            plt.close()

        def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25,model_name = "kaggle"):
            data_dir="./data/"
            num_epochs=100
            device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            val_loss_gph=[]
            train_loss_gph=[]
            val_acc_gph=[]
            train_acc_gph=[]
            since = time.time()

            best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
            best_acc = 0.0

            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs))
                # print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs)) 
                logger.log(logging.INFO, '-' * 10)
                # print('-' * 10)

                # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
                for phase in ['train', 'val']:
                    if phase == 'train':
                        model.train()  # Set model to training mode
                    else:
                        model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

                    running_loss = 0.0
                    running_corrects = 0

                    # Iterate over data.        
                    for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                        
                        inputs = inputs.to(device)
                        labels = labels.to(device)

                        # forward
                        # track history if only in train
                        with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                            outputs = model(inputs)
                            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1) #was (outputs,1) for non-inception and (outputs.data,1) for inception
                            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                            # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                            if phase == 'train':
                                optimizer.zero_grad()
                                loss.backward()
                                optimizer.step()

                        # statistics
                        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                        running_corrects += torch.sum(preds.detach() == labels.data)

                    if phase == 'train':
                        scheduler.step()

                    epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
                    epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

                    if phase == 'train':
                        train_loss_gph.append(epoch_loss)
                        train_acc_gph.append(epoch_acc.item())
                    if phase == 'val':
                        val_loss_gph.append(epoch_loss)
                        val_acc_gph.append(epoch_acc.item())
                    
                    plot(val_loss_gph,train_loss_gph, "Loss")
                    plot(val_acc_gph,train_acc_gph, "Accuracy")

                    logger.log(logging.INFO, '{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
                        phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))
                    # print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
                    #     phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

                    # deep copy the model
                    if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc >= best_acc:
                        best_acc = epoch_acc
                        best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
                        torch.save(model.state_dict(), data_dir+"/"+model_name+".pth")
                        logger.log(logging.INFO, '==>Model Saved')
                        # print('==>Model Saved')

                logger.log(logging.INFO, '')
                # print()
                

            time_elapsed = time.time() - since
            logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
                time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
            # print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
                # time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
            logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))
            # print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

            # load best model weights
            model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
            return model

        # Getting Proba distribution
        def get_probability(image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name):
            data_dir="./data/"
            num_epochs=100
            logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Getting the Probability Distribution')
            # print("\nGetting the Probability Distribution")
            testloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets['val'],batch_size=1)

            model=model.eval()

            correct = 0
            total = 0
            import csv
            import numpy as np
            f = open(data_dir+'/'+model_name+".csv",'w+',newline = '')
            writer = csv.writer(f)

            with torch.no_grad():
                num = 0
                temp_array = np.zeros((len(testloader),num_classes))
                for data in testloader:
                    images, labels = data
                    labels=labels.cuda()
                    outputs = model(images.cuda())
                    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    total += labels.size(0)
                    correct += (predicted == labels.cuda()).sum().item()
                    prob = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs, dim=1)
                    temp_array[num] = np.asarray(prob[0].tolist()[0:num_classes])
                    num+=1
            logger.log(logging.INFO, "Accuracy = ",100*correct/total)
            # print("Accuracy = ",100*correct/total)

            for i in range(len(testloader)):
                writer.writerow(temp_array[i].tolist())
            f.close()
        
            
        def learningPart(self, data_dir,num_epochs):
            mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
            std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
            
            # data_dir="./data/"
            
            global data_transforms
            data_transforms = {
                'train': transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
                ]),
                'val': transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
                ]),
            }

            global image_datasets
            image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                                data_transforms[x])
                        for x in ['train', 'val']}
            
            global dataloaders
            dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=16,
                                                        shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
                        for x in ['train', 'val']}
            
            global dataset_sizes
            dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
            
            global class_names
            class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes
            
            global num_classes
            num_classes = len(class_names)
            
            global device
            device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            # print(class_names)
            logger.log(logging.INFO, class_names)

        #Get probability distributions from the 4 models
            # global num_epochs
            num_epochs = 100

            global criterion
            criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            
            # Get a batch of training data
            global inputs, classes
            inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))

            model = models.vgg11_bn(pretrained = True)
            optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, momentum = 0.99)
            step_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size = 10, gamma=0.1)
            num_ftrs = model.classifier[0].in_features
            model.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
            model = model.to(device)
            model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, step_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=num_epochs, model_name = 'Kaggle_vgg11')
            get_probability(image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name='Kaggle_vgg11')

            model = models.googlenet(pretrained = True)
            optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, momentum = 0.99)
            step_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size = 10, gamma=0.1)
            num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
            model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
            model = model.to(device)
            model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, step_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=num_epochs, model_name = 'Kaggle_googlenet')
            get_probability(image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name='Kaggle_googlenet')

            model = models.squeezenet1_1(pretrained = True)
            optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, momentum = 0.99)
            step_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size = 10, gamma=0.1)
            model.classifier[1] = nn.Conv2d(512, num_classes, kernel_size=(1,1), stride=(1,1))
            model = model.to(device)
            model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, step_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=num_epochs, model_name = 'Kaggle_squeezenet')
            get_probability(image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name='Kaggle_squeezenet')

            model = models.wide_resnet50_2(pretrained = True)
            optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, momentum = 0.99)
            step_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size = 10, gamma=0.1)
            num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
            model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
            model = model.to(device)
            model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, step_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=num_epochs, model_name = 'Kaggle_wideresnet')
            get_probability(image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name='Kaggle_wideresnet')
            
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        mainLabel = tk.Label(self,text='Deep Learning', font=('Arial',25,'bold'),fg="white", bg="black",height=2).pack()
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Deep Learning", command=lambda:[threading.Thread(target=learningPart(self,"./data/",100)).start()],borderwidth=0, width=50, height=3, fg="pink", bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 16,'bold'))
        b1.pack()
        
        T= ScrolledText(self, state='disabled', height=35)
        self.log_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.queue_handler = QueueHandler(self.log_queue)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
        self.queue_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(self.queue_handler)
        # Start polling messages from the queue
        T.after(100, self.poll_log_queue)
        # T = tk.ScrolledText(self, height = 35, width = 70, state='disable')
        T.pack()
        
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back To Main Page",command=lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage),borderwidth=0, width=50, height=3, fg="pink", bg="black", font=("Helvetica", 16,'bold'))
        b2.pack()
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using threading properly. `target=learningPart(self,"./data/",100)` will immediately run `learningPart(self,"./data/",100)` before passing the result to the `target` attribute.

Comment: So that means I need to open a function, for example
def threading():
    # Call work function
    t1=Thread(target=learningPart(self,"./data/",100))
    t1.start()

Comment: and b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Deep Learning", command=lambda:[threading.Thread(target=threading]) like this?